# Multiple choice question related to a real valued function

Tags: real-analysis

[image]
My attempt: I have computed $Rf'(1)=c$ and $Lf'(1)=2a.$ Now for $f'$ to be continuous ,we must have , $c=2a$ . But I am not sure how to find $b$?Also,where should I use the fact that $f$ is increasing in $(0,\infty)?$ Can someone point me in the right direction? please help.Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Continuity of $f'$ at $1$ is simply equivalent to $c=2a$. No need to equate this with $f(1)$. And $f$ is increasing if and only if $2a>0$ and $c>0$. This leaves room, for infinitely many $(a,b,c)$. So D.

Comment: @julien Thanks a lot.I have got it.